# Synology DS cloud App does no longer sync correctly on tablet

Tags: synchronization, nas, synology

I sync my PC with my tablet. While the PC was able to sync the video to my Synology NAS, my tablet always started the download then apparently could not finish it. The download bar stops right at the finish line and after a few seconds the download of the video restarts. The app sometimes crashed as well.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was rather simple - I had a broken filename. I accidently pasted a newline character in the filename. The Android filesystem apparently cannot handle newline characters in file names and thus was not able to store the file. After removing the new line character everything worked fine again.

On Linux you can use `find . -name $'*\n*'` to find the erroneous file. Rename it and you should be good to go!